# How to split a string into different parts in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have 3 strings in PHP which contains a list of test input for a function with two parameters.

I want to parse the strings and get the individual parameter values.

example:

```
"a,b" => "a", "b"

"/"string_param1/", /"string_param2/""  => "string_param1", "string_param2"

"[list,1], [list,2]"   => "[list,1]", "[list,2]"
```

Comment: Explode the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply use `explode()` because you have other factor to accommodate.

`preg_split()` is the function to call when you want to perform a variable explosion.

`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is a very handy technique for this case because it consumes the "protected" substrings and then disqualifies them as possible splitting points.

The `, ?` (comma - space - questionmark) means that you want to explode on every comma that is optionally trailed by a space.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1d06e00cdd8a235869ecb8409b89811a2d5b799))

```
$test_strings = ['a,b', '/"string_param1/", /"string_param2/"', '[list,1], [list,2]'];

foreach ($test_strings as $string) {
    $result[] = preg_split('~(?:\".*?\"|\[[^[]*])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|, ?~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '/"string_param1/"',
    1 => '/"string_param2/"',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '[list,1]',
    1 => '[list,2]',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For strings 1 and 3 you can use the `explode` function to split the string at the comma like so:

    `$a = 'a,b';
    $a_params = explode(',', $a);`

But for the second string you can run `str_replace` to get rid of unwanted quotes or backslashes so you can use `explode`.

[str_replace() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

[explode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I am downvoting because this simply doesn't satisfy the OP's requirements.  I'm not sure why this received two upvotes.